Querying number field not displaying correct decimal values
I have defined the field type as currency(16,2) with 2 decimal places, but when Querying in developer console or workbench getting different value like 2.0 for 2.00 or 2 or 2.0 as input value i want to display as 2.00 for all the three cases.

how and where are you going to display this value?  is it an LWC component, VF page, or page layout?

I want know why the values are displaying like that while querying I want to display number with .00 and I am giving input in lwc and assigning the value to apex method parameter which is string type, after that a I am converting this into decimal by using Decimal.valueOf() and assigning it to filed value.

@OleksandrBerehovskyi, I want to display this value with two decimals in case description field, while creating new case in apex.

When you use SOQL, it will display just enough digits to show the precision. Example: "1.20" is unnecessary since "1.2" is sufficient precision.  If you want a fixed decimal display, you must output using Apex / LWC.
